# El compilador de C# solo soporta hasta la versión 5

Tags: c#, .net, compilador, microsoft

He configurado la variable de entorno path de .Net Framework:

[image: Versión de .Net Framework]

[image: Variable de entorno de .Net Framework]

Una vez realizado esto, según la CLI la versión que tengo es la 4.8.9032.0:

[image: Versión de .Net Framework]

Yo pensaba que .Net Framework 4.8 soportaba hasta la versión 7 de c#, por ende, me queda la duda del mensaje que solo me permite usar hasta la versión 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por razones desconocidas para nosotros, aparentemente el Runtime incluye el compilador y otras herramientas que esperaríamos estén en el SDK solamente.

Sin embargo, ese no es el compilador que utiliza Visual Studio. Si tienes Visual Studio instalado y quieres compilar un proyecto sin él, deberías usar la [consola de desarrollador de Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022).

Básicamente es un acceso directo que puedes encontrar en el Menú de Inicio. Lo que hará es abrir un terminal de toda la vida, o un Powershell, con la configuración necesaria para poder ejecutar cualquier programa del SDK.

Puedes ver cómo encontrarla en Windows 10 en este GIF que se encuentra en el enlace anterior:

[image: Procedimiento para abrir la consola de desarrollador]

Si no tienes Visual Studio, probablemente encuentres un compilador para C# 7 en el [paquete para desarrolladores](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48).

Comment: Gracias Mateo, tu respuesta me aclara la situación.

Comment: De nada. Aunque me deja un gusto amargo no haber podido contar esas razones desconocidas. No pude encontrar mucha información al respecto.